# Selenium python: Unable to parse data in <object> tag with #document section - Error:NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium-webdriver-python

How do I get the title-2 as shown in attached image. I don't know how to switch to **#document** and fetch the title as it's not under . When I write print(driver.title) gives the title-1 from  section (as shown in image). Actually main screen divided into 2 sections, HTML code for Section 1 is found between parent  to # document and section 2's HTML code found onwards #document. So able to access the elements from section 1 and not able to access any element from the section 2, it gives NoSuchElmentException. My question is how do I fetch the element from #document.  One more thing when I logged into application the main page is get refresh automatically, can it causing an issue? Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks .
[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT5td.jpg)

I tried to check whether more than one windows are there, no there is a single window, whether it is under ? no it is not. Also tried by putting wait command to avoid NoSuchElementException. Not a single element able to search which are under #document.